# Is there a location where the construction of Powershell 6.0 cmdlets are documented?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-core

Is there a place where Powershell 6.0's cmdlets are documented in an easy to read manner, kind of like how the .NET framework is documented here?

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/

I already tried digging through the github for PS Core, but I'm rather lost and not entirely sure what I'm doing.
I know some C# but don't know the .NET framework all that well so it confuses me, as well as I'm a bit of a novice programmer when it comes to actually building fully fledged applications, so it's rather easy to get lost and I don't think I could find anything in that giant haystack of code and files.
I assume most, if not all cmdlets are written in C#, so that doesn't bother me, but I do wonder if there was a place where they could be written in PS code.

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a better starting point for you:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/

PowerShell functions can either be written in PowerShell's own scripting language and you will fidn those in `.ps1` or `.psd1`. Writing a function in .Net is a bit more involved but the docs should guide you. Make yourself familiar with the difference between Windows PowerShell and PowerShell Core please (the former is based on the full .Net framework and ships pre-installed with Windows and the latter is built using .Net Core/Standard and needs to be installed)